# How to show Firebase firestore colletions of nearby collections by location inside a radius of the device using Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-maps, google-cloud-firestore, geolocation

I am developing an App using Flutter, like a food delivery app. So I have the restaurant app, and the end-user app.

**What I am doing at the moment**

Getting the company address (geoLocation), and using lat and lng with geohash to store the location on the Firestore collection for the Restaurants. And for the end-user app, I am getting the current device location.

**What I am trying to achieve**

On the end-user app, I want to create a list, like uber eats, to show the nearby restaurants, using the current location of the end-user device, with the Restaurant location on our Firestore.

I am using GeoFlutterFire dependencie to achieve the locations.

**The function I have**

```
Stream nearbyComp() async* {
    var pos = await location.getLocation();

    GeoFirePoint point =
        geo.point(latitude: pos.latitude, longitude: pos.longitude);
    final CollectionReference users =
        _firebaseFirestore.collection("Companies");

    double radius = 10;
    String field = 'location';

    Stream<List<DocumentSnapshot>> stream = geo
        .collection(collectionRef: users)
        .within(center: point, radius: radius, field: field, strictMode: true);

    yield stream;
  }
```

**Where I am trying to display the List**

```
Container(
            child: StreamBuilder(
              stream: nearbyComp(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                  return Text("Loading");
                }
                return Container(
                  child: Text("companyName"), // This needs to be changed to a list? Display company name, image, etc, here.
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
```

**Current issue**

The issue is, I can't find a way to display the Restaurant Profile on the end-user screen, like image, name, etc. I think I need a ListView.Builder, but don't know how to do it with the Stream on the nearComp() function.

**My Firestore**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In your streambuilder's return:

```
return ListView(children: [
for (var item in snapshot.data) 
  ListTile( title: Text ( item["companyEmail"])) 
// Or use item.data()["companyEmail"], I didn't work with //geoFire, but these should work since it's firebase.
])
```

Comment: type '_AsBroadcastStream<List<DocumentSnapshot>>' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable<dynamic>' It's returning this :/ and item.data() does not work either

Comment: Hey, do you have any ideas on what can be wrong?